# How can I open an Activity using the name as string via intent?

Tags: java, android

I want to use String variable containig the name of an activity, and i want to open the activity via in intent.
For example:

```
next = "foo.class";
Intent baslat = new Intent(this,next);
```

"next" is my value. I think using variable is impossible because eclipse don't let me use two arguments.
How can I solve this problem?

Edit: I am trying to go to "foo.class"

Edit: I solve the problem, You are all so nice and pretty :D, kisses for all, thank you very much!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: No need to use as a String: `new Intent(this, foo.class);`

Comment: Why do you want to use a `String`?  You may need to post some additional code to explain what you're trying to do.  If you really need to convert a string to a `Class`, you probably have the design all wrong, but [`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) may give you what you think you need.

Comment: you are probably looking for `setComponentName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, use the method `Class.forName()`

```
String myClass = "foo.class";
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Class.forName(myClass));
startActivity(myIntent );
```

Comment: You got me wrong. I am trying to go to "foo.class" that is called "next". I dont need putString or something else

Comment: putString() is not a method of Intent

Answer (score 1):

There is a method [Intent.putExtra()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). You can use this method to add extra variables inside your intent object.

```
String next = "foo.class";
Intent baslat = new Intent();
baslat.putExtra("my_tag", next);
```

Comment: You got me wrong. I am trying to go to "foo.class" that is called "next". I dont need putString or something else

Answer (score 0):

Intent.putExtra() is what you're looking for.

```
next = "foo.class";
Intent baslat = new Intent(/*intent action goes here*/);
basalt.putExtra(/*data name*/, next);
```

If foo.class is where you're headed, then use Intent(Context packageContext, Class cls):

```
Intent baslat = new Intent(this, foo.class);
startActivity(basalt);
```

Comment: You got me wrong. I am trying to go to "foo.class" that is called "next". I dont need putString or something else